# Trouble Getting JSON Data

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift

I am pretty new to back end programming with JavaScript and have written some code to query a database and return the results as JSON. It seems to be working correctly in the browser, but my iOS code isn't getting any data from it. I have it running locally for now while testing. If you look in my Swift that gets the data from the URL, I'm getting the NO JSON from the print statement in the catch.

**JavaScript**

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');
var sql = require("mssql");
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var membershipNumber;
var queryString;

var app = express();

app.get('/membership/:number', function (req, res) {
    console.log("\nPARAMS:");
    console.log(req.params.number);

    membershipNumber = req.params.number;
    queryString = util.format('SELECT major_key, company, status, paid_thru FROM name WHERE major_key = \'%s\' and member_record = 1', membershipNumber);
    console.log("\nQUERY:");
    console.log(queryString);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    membershipStatusQuery(queryString, res);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var dictionary = [];
    dictionary.push({
        key: "none"
    });
    var jsonDict = JSON.stringify(dictionary);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(jsonDict);
});

function membershipStatusQuery(query, response) {
    var config = {
        server: 'DB_Server',
        database: 'testDB',
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        port: 1433
    };

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config);

    connection.connect().then(function () {
        var req = new sql.Request(connection);
        req.query(query).then(function (recordset) {
            connection.close();
            response.send(results);
        })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                connection.close();
                response.send(err);
            });
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.send(err);
        });
}

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port %s", port);
});
```

**RESULTS**

```
[{"major_key":"0001354648","company":"Membership of David Metzgar","status":"A","paid_thru":"2017-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

**iOS Swift Code**
Class to get JSON from URL:

```
import UIKit

class GetJSON: NSObject {

    func getJSONFrom(urlString: String) -> JSON {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        var data = Data()

        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        } catch {
            print("No JSON")
            // TODO: Display error
        }

        let json = JSON(data: data)
        return json
    }
}
```

Method from another class to use JSON:

```
func getQueryResultsJSON() {
        print("http://localhost:1337/membership/\(memberNumberTextField.text!)")
        // let jsonURL = "http://localhost:1337/membership/\(memberNumberTextField.text!)"
        let jsonURL = "http://localhost:1337/membership/0001354648"
        let getJSON = GetJSON()
        self.resultsArray = getJSON.getJSONFrom(urlString: jsonURL)
        if let dictionary = resultsArray?[0].dictionaryObject {
            if let status = dictionary["status"] {
                if status as! String == "A" {
                    print(dictionary)
                    print("Provided membership is active")
                    // membership is active
                    // TODO: save info and display membership card
                } else {
                    print(dictionary)
                    print("Provided membership is NOT active")
                    // membership is not active
                    // TODO: display alert
                }
            } else {
                print("DOESN'T EXIST!")
                // membership number does not exist
                // TODO: display alert
            }
        } else {
            print("NOTHING!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        let url = NSURL(string: "your url")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        // request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // request.httpBody = jsonData
        //request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
            if error != nil {

                return
            }

            do {
                let userObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: String]
                if userObject != nil {

                    // do something
                } 

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
                print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Comment: I'm using SwiftyJSON and all of my code in GetJSON works with other web APIs.